# How can I refactor this unfortunate partial class?

Tags: design-patterns, refactoring, partial-classes

I've started working with a Linq2Sql data access layer and it has a "God Class" partial class, the other partial of which is a generated EntitySet. This partial class does all kinds of things, like serialize itself to Json, make database calls and various utility functions, as well as define a host of convenience properties and methods for interacting with the model it "partials" with.

As a side effect of this, it's impossible to serialize, and all the other problems with the "God Class" antipattern.

What's a good design pattern for splitting these classes up to get better separation of concerns? I'd like to place an emphasis on ease-of-refactoring, as this class is sprinkled throughout the application.

Comment: One thing to say immediately is that you should adhere to SOLID principles.  Make sure that you implement S - single responsibility - however you separate make sure that serialisation is handled by one class, db calls by another.

Comment: +1 @SachinKainth, SOLID principles can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID

Answer (score 2):

As with most refactorings of legacy code I'd suggest introducing an intermediate adapter class (see [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)) that to begin with solely delegates to the old functionality. Then as the new code is introduced, the wrapper can begin to delegate the work to the new code. Until, eventually, the wrapper can be removed entirely.

Comment: +1 because this actually tells something the OP doesn't already know.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I would say that you should write tests (unit or integration) wherever you can to discover/verify the functionality of the various parts of the class and then when you refactor you will be sure that you haven't broken any of the functionality as you will have a set of regression tests to fall back on.

Comment: I agree its absolutely important to have a good test suite when doing this sort of refactor to guarantee (as much as can be done with tests) the behavior before and after the changes.